# Wordpress .htaccess for complex need

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have **wordpress** installed in my root directory...

I have two sub folders called **test1** and **marketing** in root folder.

Now when i try to open pdf files inside my **marketing** folder, my wordpress site redirects me to **404 error** .

for example, i am trying to open following link

`http://example.com/marketing/test.pdf`
it redirects me to `http://example.com/404`

Now for scenario two , I have installed wordpress in **test1** too.

But for some links of **test1** wordpress , it also redirects me to 404 page.

for example, i am trying to open following link

`http://example.com/test1/portfolio/interior-site`
it redirects me to `http://example.com/404`

My root directory's .htaccess is as below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My **test1** folder's .htaccess is below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Try: `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/test1/404.php`

Comment: I do not need that.. How can i open http://example.com/marketing/test.pdf  instead redirecting it to 404.

Comment: It shouldn't because wordpress rewriterules only apply to non existent files (see -f tag), it should work right away without any change